# I want to move a button to the far most top of a stack panel by clicking it

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<StackPanel Name="ButtonsStack" Width="250" >
    <Button Name="button1" Content="button 1" Height="30"/>
    <Button Name="button2" Content= "button 2" Height="30" MouseDown="button2_MouseDown"/>
</StackPanel>
```

"""I want button2 to move above button 1 when I click button2"""

Comment: You forgot your xaml?

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are just ui elements, what you are concerned about is the content needs to switch. On the button click, simply switch the content as shown below in the pseudo code:

```
bool IsButton2 { get; set; }

public void button2_MouseDown(...)
{
    IsButton2 = !IsButton2;
    button1.Content = (IsButton2) ? "Button 2" : "Button 1";
    button2.Content = (IsButton2) ? "Button 1" : "Button 2";
}
```